# Restful API debugging

Tags: rest, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I want to debug the Rest API service project with visual studio 2017.I use breakpoints , the breakpoints becomes yellow at catch exception when I hover my mouse over the e.message but I can not see the error message, also I can not see the error with Debug.Writeline in output window  .

Comment: Please post some code.  Are you sure the url of the rest service is accessible?

Comment: Yes,I use postman and can get the response from url.

Comment: When I use  " var response = await client.GetAsync("Url") " I can not get response and catch exception become active but  I can not see the error message .so I can not figure that out what is the problem that my response is not successful .catch (Exception e)
            {                
                Debug.WriteLine("GetAsync {0}", e.Message);
                
            } and I can not see the error on output window.

Comment: what is the url?  Wondering if maybe the emulator or phone cannot access the rest service.

Comment: This is a emulator.

Comment: Can you hit the url of the rest service from the emulator's browser?

Comment: I am new in web service. When I use the Url in emulator it gives "access forbidden" for this API I have basic authentication. I don't know how to test the Url in emulator browser I just know Postman for testing.

Comment: I think I found the problem as I use await/Async , for try/catch I have to use AggregateException  not Exception .I am working on it an let you know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug an API, it is not the IDE that matters. You need to think of the full flow of the API invocation. If someone is complaining that an API is not working, then you need to divide and conquer the problem. The article on [debugging API driven applications](https://integrationhelp.com/debugging-api-driven-applications/) detail the layers you need to be aware of. You need to consider

- Client application
- Client to API connection
- API logic
- API to database connection
- Speed of API and client applications

In simple terms, if you want to see if only the API implementation works, see if there is a response for the request being sent to the API. Then check the logic. Then check the connection to database, and so on ...